# Neo4jClient Get All Referenced Nodes

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

In my application I have classes/nodes like:
-person
-activity
-company

I can create relationships between:
- person and company
- company and activity
- activity and person
- person and person
- company and company

So. It is possible, that a specific activity is related to a person and to an company. The company is mostly the root. But there is no real hierarchy. It's more like a mesh structure.

(I know how to create the relationships etc. I saw already some tutorials. :) )

Now. I want to get all directly related relationships with nodes of a specific node. 
I DON'T want to fetch the related data by the relationship type. I want (when possible) one query, which reads all relationships and the according nodes.

And the second requirement: When I have retrieved all related relationships and nodes, I want get the relationships (if any exists) between these nodes!

So it would be very cool to solve this with 2 queries!

Any ideas? 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
start company = node(2) match company-[?:employs]-> person return company, person
```

See docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-query-lang.html for details.

Otherwise, you can look up the companies, persons etc in an index, e.g.

```
start comp=node:Companies(name='Cocal Cola'), person=node:Persons(name='Bob') ...
```

Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: The first query looks good! Query like this "node(*) match n-[r?]->m return n,type(r),m" returns all connected nodes. I don't have to query for each relationship type.  And I see the relationships between the "subnodes" too. For example: A and B are connected to C. And between these subnodes (A,B) exists an relationship too.

Comment: Now i just don't know how to implement this in neo4jclient. Because the nodes A,B and C and the relationships are different classes. And when I fetch the data, I wan't to cast the nodes in the appropriate classes/types.... :/